# azure java sdk for az get token programatically

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-java-sdk

I am studying the azure java sdk and I did not find a wrapper method for

```
az account get-access-token --resource api://xxxxx.microsoft.com/YYYY/ZZZZ
```

This request works properly from windows batch but i cannot run using azure java sdk.
I'll appreciate any feedback about how to run this command using azure java sdk

Best Regards,
Aurelian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> azure java sdk for az get token programatically:-

You can use the below java spring-boot code to retrieve the access token and it worked for me as follows.

`RestApiController.java`

```bash
package com.myapp.restcall.controller;  
import java.util.Collections;  
import org.json.JSONObject;  
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;  
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;  
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;  
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;  
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;  
import org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap;  
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;  
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;  
  
@RestController  
public class RestApiController {  
  
   @GetMapping(value = "/gettoken")  
   public static String getToken() throws Exception {  
   String url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/token";  
  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();  
  headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);  
  MultiValueMap<String, String> inputMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();  
  
  inputMap.add("grant_type", "client_credentials");  
  inputMap.add("client_id", "CLIENT_ID");  
  inputMap.add("client_secret", "CLIENT_SECRET");  
  inputMap.add("resource", "https://management.core.windows.net/");  
  HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> entity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(inputMap,  
  headers);  
  RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();  
  ResponseEntity<String> response = template.postForEntity(url, entity, String.class);  
  JSONObject myjson = new JSONObject(response.getBody());  
  String data = (String) myjson.get("access_token");  
  System.out.println(data);  
  String access_token = data;  
 return access_token;  
  
  }  
}
```

Replace `CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET & TENANT_ID` in the above java code before executing it.

To build the program, use below commands in the IDE terminal.

```
mvn clean install
mvn spring-boot:run
```

[image]

*Token generated at* `localhost:8080/gettoken` *successfully*.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Jahnavi, the main issue which I have is that I am not able to get that client secret, I will test you code and I will let you know.

Comment: Goto Azure Active Directory -> Search for App registrations -> create a new registration and then you will be able to see the `certificates and secrets` options under `manage` and create a `new client secret` as [shown](https://i.imgur.com/bpONpt7.png). Copy the secret value and add it in the above code. @aurelianr

Comment: unfortunately i don t have access in that zone in my company azure cloud,

Comment: If you need to use azure java sdk, you have to create an appid and secret for sure. It is not possible to authenticate without these. @aurelianr